# Subdomain from $_GET value

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, get, subdomain, wildcard-subdomain

In my website user can search different word in different country, so i have this type of url :

http://example.com/search.php?search=keyword&page=1&siteID=US

If user add some field search will be :

http://example.com/search.php?minPrice=1&maxPrice=500&search=keyword&page=1&siteID=US

Now, i want create subdomain for every siteID i have preset in my script.

So if user call a search with siteID=US i want redirect to http://us.example.com/

If user search siteID=FR i want the subdomain is like this http://fr.example.com/

I need to set wildcard for my subdomain?

How i can in php create a function for associate every destination to proper subdomain?

Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

redirect By Php

```
$validCountry = ['us','fr'....];
if(in_array($_GET['siteID'],$validCountry)){
$nQuery = str_replace('siteID='.$_GET['siteID'],'',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI]);
header ("Location: http://".$_GET['siteID'].'example.com/'.$nQuery);
}else{
//...
}
```

but i think it is better to use javascript in search form to live redirect

onsubmit form document location ... etc

Answer (score 0):

From your question, i can see **siteID=FR** or **siteID=US** are coming. Why cant you just keep a check on top of the php search page as below:(Here i am just checking if siteID is having any codes if yes then i am redirectinng to perticular URL)

```
    $siteID=$_REQUEST['siteID'];//send rest of the parameters along if required
if (!empty($siteID)){    
    $country_list = array('US','FR');
    if (in_array($siteID, $country_list)) {
    $url = "http://$siteID.example.com/";
    header('location:'$url);
    }
}
```